# Error Code -1011 with status code 401

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking, jsonserializer

I am using AFNetworking to post a username and password, so that I can get a JSON response.
I am readily getting JSON response in POSTMAN client as in below snapshot :
[image]

But then, whenever I hit the same URL with the AFNetworking library :

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:urlString parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

The error I get is as below :
[image]

I even tried adding the below code, but it always gave the same error response :

```
AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializerRequest = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[serializerRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

manager.requestSerializer = serializerRequest;

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

How can I get the JSON response as in the postman client.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: in the failure block what you have if you add NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.responseObject); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTTP Response code `401` is not in your `acceptableStatusCodes` list. AFNetworking will not proceed to deserialise the object. But instead create an NSError object which is what you are seeing outputted.

This functionality can be found `AFURLResponseSerialization.m:132`.

If you would like to update the HTTP codes you wish to accept you can use:

`self.acceptableStatusCodes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(200, 200)];`

Otherwise if you are confident that the request contains JSON body, you can still access the data from the NSError that is produced as its contained in the `userInfo` with the key
 `AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey` and deserialise it manually.

More information: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2410#issuecomment-63304245